# Getting Error while try to register destination in amazon mws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I try to get a notification of offer changes in my products.
so I write my code as per documentation. but it throws error of access denied. 
I don't think there is any error in the code.
Can I have to use same AWS account as MWS Account, because at now I use different MWS account and AWS account for register destination?

```
 $serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com";
 $config = array(
'ServiceURL'    => $serviceUrl . '/Subscriptions/2013-07-01',
'ProxyHost'     => null,
'ProxyPort'     => -1,
'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
);

$chanel_data_array = get_all_chanel_keys($user_id);
foreach ($chanel_data_array as $key => $value) {
$data = [
    'marketplace_id' => 'ATVPDKIKX0DER',
    'access_key'     => $value['access_key'],
    'secret_key'     => $value['secret_key'],
    'merchant_id'    => $value['seller_id'],
    'chanel_id'      => $value['chanel_id'],
];

register_notification($data, $config);
break;
}

function createDestination($sqsUrl) {

$attribute = new MWSSubscriptionsService_Model_AttributeKeyValue;
$attribute->setKey('sqsQueueUrl');
$attribute->setValue($sqsUrl);
$attributeList = new MWSSubscriptionsService_Model_AttributeKeyValueList();
$attributeList->setmember($attribute);
$destination = new MWSSubscriptionsService_Model_Destination();
$destination->setAttributeList($attributeList);
$destination->setDeliveryChannel('SQS');
return $destination;
}

function register_notification($data, $config) {

$service = new MWSSubscriptionsService_Client(
    $data['access_key'],
    $data['secret_key'],
    APPLICATION_NAME,
    APPLICATION_VERSION,
    $config);

$request = new MWSSubscriptionsService_Model_RegisterDestinationInput();
$request->setSellerId($data['merchant_id']);
// $request->setMWSAuthToken(MWSAUTHTOKEN);
$request->setMarketplaceId($data['marketplace_id']);

$createDestination = createDestination('https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/34aajm0916646045/product');

$request->setDestination($createDestination);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($createDestination);
echo "<br>";
invokeRegisterDestination($service, $request);
}
```